# Is the ActiveRecord query_cache supposed to be enabled in production console by default or not in rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I just noticed that the rails query cache is not enabled in our production console. I recall it being so at an earlier point and we sure have not disabled it explicitly in any of our first party code.

I cannot seem to find any authoritative documentation saying if/where it's enabled by default?

```
irb(main):011:0> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.query_cache_enabled
=> false
```